# NSMutableDictionary input into an array is somehow missing info on the way out

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have a mutable array (downloadQueue) containing custom objects (AssetNode) and each object has an NSMutableDictionary as a property.

```
@interface AssetNode : NSObject {
    NSMutableDictionary* allData;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary* allData;
```

When I remove an AssetNode from the downloadQueue, the .allData property for the remaining AssetNode objects somehow gets modified and ends up missing some value/key pairs.

```
-(void)removeAssetNodeFromQueue:(AssetNode*)aNode{
    NSMutableArray *temp = [NSMutableArray array]; 
    for (AssetNode* node in downloadQueue)
    {
        if ([aNode.nodeId isEqualToString:node.nodeId])
        {
            [temp addObject:node];
        }
    }
    [downloadQueue removeObjectsInArray:temp];
}
```

Any idea why this happens or how to maintain the integrity of the dictionary info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an NSLog or breakpoint at every point in your code where `allData` is modified. Log the entire dictionary. I would expect that you have a bug in your code, rather than the NSMutableDictionary accidentally losing your data.

Comment: Turns out that there was a spot where the allData was being modified when it shouldn't have been.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, retain the dictionary of the object being removed

```
if ([aNode.nodeId isEqualToString:node.nodeId])
{
    [temp addObject:node];
    [temp.allData retain];
}
```

But I suggest storing the allData into another variable, otherwise you'll be leaking memory.

Check out apples Automatic Reference Counting (ARC), this doc is nice:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Comment on my answer if you'd like for me to quickly explain retain count to you.

Cheers